# Undecidable unary languages (also known as Tally languages)

Tags: reference-request, turing-machines, undecidability

An exercise that was in a past session is the following:

> Prove that there exists an undecidable subset of $\{1\}^*$

This exercise looks very strange to me, because I think that all subsets are decidable.

Is there a topic that I should read to find a possible answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\{1\}^*$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb N$. There are uncountably many subsets of both $\{1\}^*$ and $\Bbb N$.

Perhaps you are confused with the fact that there are only countably many *finite* subsets of $\{1\}^*$ (and $\Bbb N$).

Answer (score 2):

A related question on StackOverflow is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672850/language-over-1-which-is-recognizable-but-not-decidable). Also the answer by [Haile](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/2449/haile) to this one is there:

> Since the universe of strings over any finite alphabet is countable,
>   every language can be mapped to a subset of the natural numbers. So
>   you just have to take a Recursively enumerable language wich is not
>   decidable and map it into a subset of $\{1\}^*$.
>
> For example, in the classic version of the halting problem we
>   enumerate every turing machine into a binary string; you can now sort
>   all the turing machines and define a map $f : TM \rightarrow N$ from Turing
>   machines to integers where $f(TM) = n$ if TM is the nth Turing Machine
>   in the ordered list of all TM.
>
> Now, the halting problem for Turing Machines coded as unary numbers is
>   r.e. but not decidable.

Another related question in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743805/the-claim-that-all-languages-which-have-polynomial-circuit-are-in-pspace-is-true).