# Is the infinite language unrecognizable in a Turing machine?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata, undecidability

This question is building up on an older one, [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48381/can-input-to-a-turing-machine-be-of-infinite-length?rq=1).

But now let's say we keep $Σ=\{0,1\}$. Is the TM that accept anys ($1^x \mid x \gt 0$) recognizable?
That means 1, 11, 11111, 1111111, and so on are all accepted.

I believe the TM is unrecognizable. This is because for it to be recognizable, we would have to halt. Yet, with no upper limit, we can have $1^\infty$ - meaning we will never halt. Does this work?

The above was an example of a language, didn't think it would be recognizable. A better way to phrase my question is: Is there a language of any number of $1$s over $\Sigma=\{0, 1\}$ that you can make unrecognizable?

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by this being Kleene Star?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh "Kleene star of $L$" or "$L^*$" means "concatenate $x$ things from language $L$, $x \in \mathbb{N}$".

Comment: What do you mean by the TM being recognizable? A TM and the language it accepts are different things.

Comment: Rice's theorem would seem to imply that there is no TM recognizing which TMs recognize the language $\{ 1^x \mid x > 0 \}$.  Which is how I initially interpreted the question based on the wording...

Comment: @DanielSchepler Can you expand on that? I was looking into solving it using Rice's theorem as my interpretation is that it is unrecognizable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question: you're asking if the Turing machine is recognizable, but I think you mean to ask if the *language* $\{1^x \mid x \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is recognizable.

A language is recognizable if and only if we can build a Turing machine that accepts every string in the language, and does not accept any string not in the language. And we can indeed build a Turing machine that does this!

```
Algorithm:
    Check the number under the head.
    If it's 0, fail.
    If it's the end of the string, accept.
    If it's 1, move to the right and repeat.
```

The key is, while there's no upper limit, $x$ has to be a natural number—*and $\infty$ is not a natural number*. In other words, while $x$ can be arbitrarily large, it has to have some finite value. It can't actually *be* $\infty$.

Comment: So you're not allowed to make an infinite language? That was more of an example, would this apply to all languages? If we have $Σ=(0, 1)$, will every turing machine that has only $1$s be recognizable?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh Sure, the language $\{1^x \mid x \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is infinite. However, all its elements are finitely long.

Comment: I added an edit to the question, would it still remain recognizable?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh That's exactly the same language, except that you're allowing the empty string in it now.

Comment: I think a slightly different way of phrasing it is: there's a difference between being able to accept _all_ strings (which is an infinite set) vs being able to accept _any_ string (which is part of that infinite set, but is itself not infinite).

Comment: @yshavit does that mean than an infinite set (accept all strings) is not allowed/possible but accepting _any string_ from a set (which can be infinite) is allwowed/possible because _any string_ is not infinite even it's part of an infinite set? 
I'm sorry but that's confusing for me

Comment: @undefined Exactly. Think about it this way: if I gave you an integer, could you tell me if it's even? Sure, it'd be easy! And yet the set of integers is infinite. Same idea.

Comment: @undefined: The Turing Machine we consider here has one output (accept/reject) for one input. Yes, there's an infinite set of possible inputs, that logically will lead to an infinite set of outputs, but there's still a one-to-one correspondence of inputs and outputs. Also, each calculation individually is a finite process, but doing that for the whole infinite set of strings would no longer be finite.

Comment: I believe the thought behind the OP's question was not about a language containing an infinite number of strings: any non-trivial language is infinite, so that's not a problem. But the thought was about the notion of including strings _of infinite length_ in the set. If we were to allow this, it's a whole different ball game since formal languages, by definition, are collections of finite-length strings.

Answer (score 6):

Languages are sets of finite strings. Every input to a Turing machine is a finite string.  $1^\infty$ is a thing, but not in this model of computation (and usually we're more specific about what infinity we're talking about).

Comment: " Languages are sets of finite strings." This is of course _true by definition_. Infinite strings certainly do exist, e.g. the digits of 1/3 and those of pi, we just exclude such  strings from our definition here.

Comment: @MSalters And there's a whole theory of automata dealing with those infinite strings. But that's a different theory to what we're dealing with here.

Answer (score 1):

A few answers has addressed the confusion about the length of a word being infinite.

Here I would like to address the following question.

> A better way to phrase my question is: Is there a language of any number of 1s over $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ that you can make unrecognizable?

Note that if a language of any number of 1s is unrecognizable, then it is unrecognizable over any alphabet that contains 1.

That question has been answered positively [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19329/undecidable-unary-languages-also-known-as-tally-languages). I would like to add another famous "constructive" example, [**busy beaver sequence**](https://oeis.org/A028444), a.k.a. [**Rado's sigma function**](http://oeis.org/wiki/Busy_Beaver_numbers#Rado.27s_sigma_function). Let $\sigma:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ be that function. We know that $$\sigma(0)=0,\  \sigma(1)=1,\ \sigma(2)=4,\ \sigma(3)=6,\ \sigma(4)=13, \\\sigma(5)\ge4098,\ \sigma(6)\ge 1.29*10^{865},\cdots. $$

We have not determine $\sigma(5)$ yet!

The language for $\sigma$ is $$\{1^{\sigma(n)}: n\in \Bbb N\}=\{\epsilon, 1, 1111, 111111, 1111111111111, \cdots\},$$
which is undecidable.

Comment: `Note that if a language of any number of 1s is unrecognizable, then it is unrecognizable over any alphabet that contains 1.` I don't get the answer provided in the link, it seemed to contradict what you're saying. Is the busy beaver sequence a counter proof?

Comment: Please come to [chat room for unrecognizable language over unary alphabet](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89745/)

Answer (score 0):

$1^\infty$ is not an actual word in the language, since $\infty$ is not a natural number - even though the language contains infinitely many words, each word has a finite, arbitrarily large length $n$.

A language is decidable if there is a Turing Machine can decide it in a finite number of steps for each input. That's obviously true here - there is no word that will take infinitely long to process.

> The above was an example of a language, didn't think it would be recognizable. A better way to phrase my question is: Is there a language of any number of 1s over $Σ=\{0,1\}$ that you can make unrecognizable?

You mean an undecidable unary (consisting only of one symbol) language? Sure there is!

Take any language $L \in \{0,1\}^*$ that you already know to be undecidable. (For example, a language that encodes all halting Turing Machines.) Modify it a bit by adding "1" to the start of each word, to keep leading zeros.

Then let your language $L'$ consist of the word $1^n$ for every $n$ whose binary representation is in $L$. ~~As each word in $L$ can be easily turned into a word in $L'$~~*, a machine that decides $L'$ could be used to decide $L$. As $L$ is undecidable, so is $L'$.

Edit: *To be more precise: "As each binary word $w$ beginning with 1 can be converted into a word consisting of 1s $w'$ such that $w\in L$ iff $w' \in L'$..."

Comment: Nitpicking here. Suppose $L\subset \{0\}^*$ is undecidable.Then $L'=\{\epsilon\}$ (or what?) is decidable.

Comment: I think the "prefix all words with 1 to fix leading zeros" part fixes this issue, but I haven't yet thought about it in detail.